# Lookup "name" in two sheets to make sum

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a printer report with 3 Sheets.

Sheet 1 (User Monthly Report) are where my results are "pasted".
[image: User Monthly Report]

Sheet 2 (User Usage Report) holds the current printer count.
[image: User Usage Report]

Sheet 3 (User Usage Report OLD) holds the previous months printer count.
(Looks exactly like Sheet 2 (User Usage Report))

In **User Monthly Report; Column A** there are names. (eg. `Kim Pearson`)

I want to look up the name in **User Monthly Report; Column A** (`Kim Pearson`) in **User Usage Report** and **User Usage Report OLD**, and IF the name `Kim Pearson` appears in both of these sheets, then, it must ***minus*** the number in **User Usage Report; Column I** from the number in **User Usage Report OLD; Column I**.

> NOTE: `Kim Pearson` is  in row 3 on **User Usage Report**, and in row 2 on **User Usage Report OLD**. And It will be the same with all other users (They will never be in the same row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this formula in sheet 1, on row 2 :

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'User Usage Report OLD'!E:I,5,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(A2,'User Usage Report'!E:I,5,FALSE),0)
```

Comment: User7640152 you are a legend! Thanks soooo much!

Comment: What do I change to calculate the next column. (Column N)

Comment: =IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'User Usage Report OLD'!E:N,10,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(A2,'User Usage Report'!E:N,10,FALSE),0)


Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I presume when you say *minus the number* you are referring to the number in **Usage Report OLD**

```
=IF(ISERROR(Match("Kim Pearson",'User Monthly Report'!$A$1:$A$10,0)),0,IFERROR(-Match("Kim Pearson",'User Usage Report OLD'!$E$1:$E$10,0),0)
```

This returns the negative value from **User Usage Report OLD** provided the user is in both of the other sheets. Add this formula to the end of your sum formula and replace the hardcoded names with cell references e.g.

```
=SUM(F2:H2)+IF(ISERROR(Match(E2,'User Monthly Report'!$A$1:$A$10,0)),0,IFERROR(-Match(E2,'User Usage Report OLD'!$E$1:$E$10,0),0)
```

Comment: Have not tried this solution as the above one worked fine for me. Thanks though for your contribution @CallumDA :)